# Shapeless record: update a field with different type

Tags: scala, shapeless

Is it possible to update an HList record with a different type, since given a list:

```
val l1 = 'field1 ->> 1 :: 'field2 ->> 2 :: HNil
```

updating `field2` with a different type would not update but add a new field:

```
l1 + ('field2 ->> "2")
//1 :: 2 :: "2" :: HNil
```

Is it possible to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by importing record ops and then use `updateWith`:

```
import shapeless.record._

l1.updateWith('field2)(_ => "2")
```

The function of the second section of `updateWith` is, roughly speaking, of type `A => B`, where `A` is the original type "pointed" by `'field2` and `B` is the type you want to transform it to. So, since the original value for `'field2` was 2, you could have done the transformation this way as well:

```
l1.updateWith('field2)(_.toString)
```